# How does one specify time interval axis on facet_wrap function in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using this package for data analysis: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wq/vignettes/wq-package.html

And the section for plotTs uses `facet_wrap` function in **ggplot2**, the example has a 5 year interval breakdown on automatic. My data is only 17 years, so my intervals are very useless with 5 year plots. First year is 1996 and last 2013, so is there to specify the breakdown of intervals specific to my case?

```
plotTs(y[, 1:4], dot.size = 1.3, ylab = "Chlorophyll in San Francisco Bay",
      strip.labels = paste("Station", 21:24), ncol = 1, scales = "free_y")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since wq is using ggplot2, you could use `scale_x_date()`. Consider this:

```
data(sfbay)
sfb <- wqData(sfbay, c(1, 3:4), 5:12, site.order = TRUE,
               type = "wide", time.format = "%m/%d/%Y")

y <- tsMake(sfb, focus = "chl", layer = c(0, 5))
y[1:4, ]
plotTs(y[, 1:4], dot.size = 1.3, ylab = "Chlorophyll in San Francisco Bay",
       strip.labels = paste("Station", 21:24), ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") + 
scale_x_date(date_breaks = "7 years", date_labels = "%Y")
```

you can play with `date_breaks()` and `date_labels`. For more information on `scale_x_date()` see http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_date.html